# Converting inline SQL to stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on an existing ASP.NET application. The current application uses a lot of inline queries. Now they want to rewrite all the queries into stored procedures only.

My problem is, these queries are very "dynamic" and the queries are concatenated based on different `if...else` conditions, for example:

```
string query = "Select * from EmpTable WHERE EmpType ='ACTIVE'";

if (conditionA == true)
query += "AND ID = 12345 ";

if (conditionB == true)
query += "AND Dept = 'Finance' ";

else
query += "AND Dept <> 'Finance' ";

if (conditionC == true)
query += "Order by EmpID";

else if (ConditionD == true)
query += "Order by Dept";
```

They also want to avoid using dynamic query. What are my options?

Edited: I know I can also build dynamic query using stored procedures, I am just wondering what are some other "less pain" options out there.

Comment: A maintenance nightmare

Comment: Well, you can pass the conditions as params to the SP and build dynamic SQL there. Not the best approach, but least painful

Comment: Dynamic queries, if done properly, can be as efficient as static queries. Perhaps "they" only have experience with badly written dynamic SQL.

Comment: If this absolutely, positively, MUST be stored procedures, would making several procedures and having conditional statements client side be possible?

For this situation, I do not recommend using stored procs, but I know how management can be once they learn a new technology.

Comment: You could try to pass parameters then insert IF @param = value  BEGIN ... END ELSE ... BEGIN .... END to build blocks of code in the Stored Procedure, but....

Comment: @dakotah.hicock Unfortunately... It MUST be in stored procedures only.

Comment: Have you considered using default parameter values for your stored procedures?  Then you can pass null from your .NET code for the parameter value, and SQL will ignore the NULL and use the parameter default.  No conditional logic involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in all the parameters you might need, and use the [IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) and/or [When](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx) clauses to create the same query as in the original program.

Alternatively you can simply build the query dynamically in the sproc itself or simply create a query for each permutation. Not necessarily fun, or clever but works and makes things easier to maintain in the future - especially when you can use it as a stepping stone for future refactoring of the sprocs.

Edit: there is one more reason to simply convert them all to sprocs - when future devs come along and want to add some SQL, they'll follow the convention and create a new sproc themselves. I imagine one reason your code is littered with dynamic SQL is because it is already littered with dynamic SQL. Maybe over time you can improve them (slap *legacy, must fix* at the top of each convert) and you'll get them to fix up the design themselves too.

Comment: I guess this is my only option for now

Comment: @C.J. this is not the most elegant solution out there, but given your requirements, I feel that gbjbaanb's solution is definitely where you should be looking. Especially the second paragraph for maintainability.

Comment: +1 for writing separate procedures for each permutation.  Maintaining 5 simple procedures is often far easier/less time consuming than maintaining a single procedure that performs 5 functions and altering one of those functions risks breaking the others.  Not to mention the gymnastics you implement to get all 5 functions working within the same procedure will likely be unreadable by future developers tasked with maintaining it.

Comment: +1 for separate procedures.  The suggested solution will perform terribly.  SQL Server doesn't like generic code.  Duplicating code is more difficult to maintain, but it will perform leaps and bounds better than using conditional logic in your WHERE clause.  If you MUST use dynamic SQL, build the string dynamically in the procedure, it will perform WAY better in the long run.