# Rewriting dynamic SQL in to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I see that this has been asked before in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641321/converting-inline-sql-to-stored-procedure) and have also looked at the `WHEN-THEN` construct but it really doesn't answer some of the questions.

Presently in the code a SQL query is built using a `StringBuilder` like this:

```
buildSearchQuery.Append("SELECT * FROM Policy WHERE Field_1 = '" + param_1 + "'");

if (Condition 2){
    buildSearchQuery.Append("AND Field_2 = '" + param_2 + "' ");
}
if (Condition 2)
{
   buildSearchQuery.Append("AND Field_3 = '" + param_3 + "' ");
}
...
```

You get the picture. There is a total of 20 of these parameter values and my task was to create a stored procedure and pass these values as parameters.

Do I create a stored procedure with all the parameters and do the logic there, if so I'm not sure how. Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Field_1 = @param_1
IF(@param_2 <> NULL)
    AND Field_2 = param_2
...
```

These parameters won't always have values so they cannot be part of the query. What is best way to make this work keeping in mind performance?

Comment: Please read:http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your stored procedure will have 3 parameters @param_1, @param_2, @param_3

Default value for these parameters can be set to NULL.

The condition inside the stored procedure will be like this

```
WHERE  ( @param_1 is NULL or field_1 = @param_1)
       AND 
       ( @param_2 is NULL or field_2 = @param_2)
       AND
       ( @param_3 is NULL or field_3 = @param_3)

OPTOIN(RECOMPILE)
```

Adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` rebuilds the execution plan every time that your query executes, with `OR` conditions this would be beneficial.

Comment: I've tried that except majority of field in the table have the `not null` constraint and an error `Procedure or function ... expects parameter '@param_1', which was not supplied.` is thrown. This is the actual code `AND (@State IS NULL OR [State] = @State)`

Comment: @Risho, in case of stored procedure you can't skip param1 and give only param2, you need to pass parma1 as NULL and then param2

Comment: I thought that was a typo. The question is then if I pass @param_1 to field_2 that won't produce the desired record, will it?

Comment: @Risho,it was a typo , what i meant is exec sp NULL, param_2 shoudl work or exec sp ( if all are NULL) or exec sp, NULL,NULL, param_3

Comment: @radar, queries written this way often benefit greatly by adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end.  That basically recompiles the query based on the current runtime values of the local variables, effectively removing the ORs and allowing index usage

Comment: If you create procedure as `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[foo] @bar bigint = NULL` you can: `EXEC dbo.foo @bar = DEFAULT`and don't bother what default is.

Answer (score 1):

Since these are all nullable parameters, you could use coalesce in the where instead of the ORs inside the parens.  I think it reads a bit better.

WHERE  coalesce(@param_1, field_1)
      AND 
       coalesce(@param_2, field_2)
       AND
       coalesce(@param_3, field_3)